# Searchable drop table JS CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to do a search list and succeeded but the list has too many items and you have to scroll a lot to get to the bottom. Then I came up with the idea to make it so my 27 categories of items are hidden in drop menus in alphabetical order.

Example: For category 1, items starting with A are in a dropmenu called A. When you click it, they should appear (which they do, but then the search function doesn't work).

Is it actually possible to search the hidden stuff in the dropmenus and to expect them to appear without me pressing the dropmenu button and just typing the items in the search box? If yes, could you explain thoroughly?

What I have so far is a searchable table with items inside:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 96%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#myUL li a {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: -1px;
  /* Prevent double borders */
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: black;
  display: block
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" maxlength="80" placeholder="Enter text" title="Text">
<ul id="myUL">
  <li><a href="#" class="header">Category 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item </a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="header">Category 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
</ul>
```

How would I go around to implementing my idea to this code, or do I have to change my code ?

Comment: Couldn't you go with your original plan, and set the overflow-y property of the container to scroll with a max-height?  That way you have a scrollable container?

Comment: Well the thing is my original plan was ok but I found out that I have 100 items in each category which would mean 27x100 on one page just doesn't look good to scroll through.